# Limit Questions and Load Faster Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hello i have a  Json file that is quite big, 20490 keywords, is there a way to load the autocomplete suggestion faster?

Json Structure:

```
{
   "list":[
      {
         "key":"12 ano",
         "value":"12 ano"
      },
      {
         "key":"12 ano administrativo",
         "value":"12 ano administrativo"
      },
      {
         "key":"12 ano contabilidade",
         "value":"12 ano contabilidade"
      }
   ]
}
```

JS Code:

```
 $(function() {
   $("#tags").autocomplete({

    source : function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("what.json", function(data) {
          var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data.list, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 6)); //
        });
    },
  });
  });
```

Comment: Load the file once when your page loads, and put the parsed JSON into a variable, instead of doing it every time the user goes to that field.

Comment: Also, if user is just adding characters, you just need to filter your previous filter

Answer (score 0):

You can preload your list of object instead of doing the query.

The autocomplete has a 300 ms of delay by default, so try doing this:

```
$(this).autocomplete({ delay: 0 });
```